# Cannot import keras.initializers

Tags: keras, python-import, importerror, keras-layer

### I have imported all  necessary modules from keras into jupyter notebook

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Dense, Dropout, Reshape, Merge, 
BatchNormalization, TimeDistributed, Lambda, Activation, LSTM, Flatten, 
Convolution1D, GRU, MaxPooling1D
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.callbacks import Callback, ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras import initializers
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

---

### but get error message

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-b13df7676198> in <module>()
 16 from keras.regularizers import l2
 17 from keras.callbacks import Callback, ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
---> 18 from keras import initializers
 19 from keras import backend as K
 20 from keras.optimizers import SGD

ImportError: cannot import name initializers
```

I have Keras version 1.2.2

Comment: initializers is part of Keras 2, it was called initializations I think in Keras 1.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
from keras import initializations
```

for Keras 1.x.y.

The `initializations` package was renamed to `initializers` in [Keras 2.0.0](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/f2fe51a9d2bc9d228e3ac374579e87595f51fef6).

Comment: I thought it might be the case but could not get any docs for 1.x.x versions to check

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  from keras import initializers
```

for Keras 2.x